# undefined local variable for find_users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, advanced-search

I am following railscast 111 for advanced search. I am getting a undefined local variable or method `find_users'. I have followed it line for line. Not sure how to fix this as I get the error after doing the search. It's pointing to NoMethodError in Searches#show. Any help would be appreciated.

show.html:

searches controller:

```
  def new
    @search = Search.new
  end

  def create
    @search = Search.new(params[:search])
    if @search.save
      redirect_to @search
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @search = Search.find(params[:id])
    @users = @search.users
  end
end
```

search.rb:

```
  attr_accessible :age, :children, :ethnicity, :gender, :religion, :zip_code

  def users
    @users ||= find_users

    private

      def find_users
        users = User.order(:id)
        users = users.where(gender: gender) if gender
        users = users.where(zip_code: zip_code) if zip_code
        users = users.where(children: children) if children
        users = users.where(religion: religion) if religion
        users = users.where(ethnicity: ethnicity) if ethnicity
        users
      end
    end
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `search.rb` you must add the method `find_users`, like so:

```
def find_users
  User.find(:all, :conditions => conditions)
end
```

Then you must also include all the method `conditions` and specify them. Please follow the railscast, it is very explicit.